# Use list comprehension to replace duplicates based on condition using other list

Tags: python, list-comprehension

It's probably easier to illustrate it with an example.

```
A = [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3]
B = [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.01, 0.02, 0.03, 0.04, 0.001, 0.001, 0.0003, 0.0003]
```

I have the two lists above.

Each element in A is duplicated a few times. The multiplicity of each element can be different (and they don't have to be ordered as here).

B contains the same number of elements as A. I want to assign to list C the smallest element from each duplicate element in A (where the smallest value comes from the corresponding values in the B list. So for the first 4 elements, it would be 0.1, for the next 4 elements, it is 0.01 in this example, and for the last 4 elements, it is the duplicate value of 0.0003 and this for each of this duplicate elements).

I would like to obtain the following list.

```
C = [0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.0003, 0.0003, 0.0003, 0.0003]
```

As the code I'm using already extensively uses list comprehension, I would like to use the same approach.

Is this possible?

Is this advisable?

I am familiar with simple conditions such as

```
C = A[B < 0.0005]
```

to give

```
C = [3]
```

but don't really have a clear idea on how to proceed here.

Comment: when you say the smallest element, do you mean the lowest index? If so, I suggest your edit the question accordingly

Comment: The smallest value. So for the first 4 elements, it would be `0.1`, for the next 4 elements, it is `0.01` in this example, and for the last 4 elements, it is the duplicate value of `0.0003`

Comment: you mean if the duplicates are in indices x,y,z,w (in `A`) so you want `min(B[[x,y,z,w]])`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a one liner, this works, assuming my comment is the correct interpretation:

```
[min([B[j] for j in [ind for ind,x in enumerate(A) if x==y]]) for y in A]
```

To break it down, you have the innermost list comprehension going over the indices and values in `A`, then the next list comprehension goes over all the values in `A` again (storing them in `y`), and is used as the condition for the previous list mentioned.
Then you use this list of indices to get all the elements in `B` (using `j`) and finally get the `min` on that list.

enumerate returns the indices and the values, into `ind` and `x`, respectively.

Comment: Works like a charm. List comprehensions are amazing... Thanks a lot! I have several other conditions like this to figure out, but I think this will help me figure it out myself.

Comment: Yes, sometimes it takes a lot of testing, but if you do it step-by-step and print the resulting lists, and add complexity, I find that it makes it much more manageable. GL

Comment: Yes indeed. At the moment, I managed to access the index of each of those minimum values. `C = [B.index(min([B[j] for j in [ind for ind,x in enumerate(A) if x==y]])) for y in A]`

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following method:

```
>>> A = [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3]
>>> B = [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.01, 0.02, 0.03, 0.04, 0.001, 0.001, 0.0003, 0.0003]
>>> AB = zip(A, B)
>>> AB_sorted = sorted(AB, key=lambda i: (i[0], -i[1]))
>>> AB_dict = dict(AB_sorted)
>>> C = [AB_dict[i] for i in A]
>>> C
[0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.0003, 0.0003, 0.0003, 0.0003]
```

This works because when you convert a `list` of `tuple`s to a `dict`, duplicate keys are overwritten by the last one.

Answer (score 1):

If you dont mind using an additional Python library named `Pandas` you can do the following:

```
import pandas as pd
A = [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3]
B = [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.01, 0.02, 0.03, 0.04, 0.001, 0.001, 0.0003, 0.0003]
df = pd.DataFrame([A, B]).T.rename(columns={0: 'A', 1: 'B'})
req_dict = {key: value for key, value in df.groupby('A')['B'].min().iteritems()}
print(df['A'].replace(req_dict))
```

Output:

```
[0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.0003, 0.0003, 0.0003, 0.0003]
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible in one line.

```
[min(y for x, y in zip(A, B) if z == x) for z in A]
```

This produces this list

```
[0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.01, 0.0003, 0.0003, 0.0003, 0.0003]
```

Comment: That's not the list `C` the OP is looking for.